# Javascript- Graphing Library

Tags: javascript, math, plot, graphing

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a simple javascript graphing library that can plot, for example, the points (5,-2) and (6,1).  I'd also like to be able to draw a line between these two points.

I've looked but so far cant find any [easy to use] library that can do this.  I would appreciate any help or links to libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: Which libraries have you deemed not "easy to use"?

Comment: gRaphael, mostly.  It refuses to work for me for some reason.

Comment: The Best: [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com)

Comment: Thanks, Chad, but that seems to be much more complicated than what I need.

Comment: What about flot? http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: Do you by chance know how to create and plot some basic points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your last comment, the way to create and plot some basic points with Flot is:

```
$(function () {
var d = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [7, 2]];
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d ]);
});
```

Here you have the doc for more complex graphs http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt and the web project page (google code)

> http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Hope this could help you, if not in this site you can found a list of javascript plotting and charting libraries

> http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/chart/20-best-javascript-charting-and-plotting-libraries/

**Edit**
If you want to plot a single point, the best way I've found is to use the options:

```
    var d = [[1,3]];
    var options = {
        series: {
          lines: { show: false },
          points: { show: true }
        }
    };
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d ], options);
```

Comment: If you want to draw more lines, you can do $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, etc. ]); ;)

Comment: Thanks, that code works.  This library looks perfect except I'm still having a tough time figuring out to plot just one point.

Comment: Points are specified as an array of arrays of two values. [0,3] is just the point placed in x=0 and y=3. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, but when I try d=[[0,3]];, nothing shows up on the graph :(